# glm with family=bernoulli vs glm with family=binomial

Tags: r, logistic, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

What is the difference in terms of the coefficients the two yielded in R; I suppose they estimate the same thing? (Log) odds ratio? Or is the latter estimating risk/relative risk ratio?

Comment: Where are you finding the `bernoulli` family? That's not one of the standard families shipped with R for use in `glm()` so it must come from elsewhere